# Change variable on the basis of last character

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change the text variable in the data set below. Namely, each row has categorical values in the object format that need to be changed, depending on the `last character` in the data set. Below you can see my dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
         'stores': ['Lexinton1','ROYAl2','Mall1','Mall2','Levis1','Levis2','Shark1','Shark','Lexinton'],
         'quantity':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['stores',
                                   'quantity'                                   
                                   ])
df
```

Now I want to change this data depending on the last character. For example, if the last charter is number `1` then I want to put the word `open`, if is number `2` then I want to put `closed`.If is not a number then I don't put anything and the text will be the same. Below you can output that is desirable

[image]

Comment: You mean based on the `quantity` column?

Comment: @Matiiss No quantity, I mean only stores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this by using [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
dmap = {1: "_open", 2: "_close"}
​
suffix = pd.to_numeric(df["stores"].str[-1], errors="coerce").map(dmap).fillna("")
​
df["stores"] = df["stores"].str[:-1].add(suffix)
```

​
Or simply by using [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) :

```
df["stores"] = df["stores"].replace({"1$": "_open", "2$": "_close"}, regex=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df)
          stores  quantity
0  Lexinton_open         1
1    ROYAl_close         1
2      Mall_open         1
3     Mall_close         1
4     Levis_open         1
5    Levis_close         1
6     Shark_open         1
7           Shar         1
8        Lexinto         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
         'stores': ['Lexinton1','ROYAl2','Mall1','Mall2','Levis1','Levis2','Shark1','Shark','Lexinton'],
         'quantity':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        }

for i in range(len(data['stores'])):
    if data['stores'][i][-1] == '1':
        data['stores'][i] = data['stores'][i][:-1]+'_open'
    elif data['stores'][i][-1] == '2':
        data['stores'][i] = data['stores'][i][:-1]+'_closed'

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['stores',
                                   'quantity'                                   
                                   ])
```